# Find day of the week for a specific festival in the next decade in Java

Tags: java, date

I've been wrestling with a programming about getting the days of the week that a specific festival falls in the next decade, so the run result will demonstrate 10 days of the week in subsequent 10 years. I have the coding, but not able to figure out how the coding works.

Here is the coding from the book, and I'm especially confused with it's algorithm about date-time.

```java
public class YearTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] date = new int[10];
        date = J(2010, 4);
        M(2010, date);
        O(2010, date);
    }

    public static int[] J(int year, int day) {
        int[] date = new int[10];
        date[0] = day;

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            if (
                ((year + i - 1) % 4 == 0) &&
                ((year + i - 1) % 100) != 0
            )
                date[i] = (date[i - 1] + 366) % 7;
            else
                date[i] = (date[i - 1] + 365) % 7;
        }

        System.out.println("January: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            System.out.println(date[i] + 1 + " ");

        return date;
    }

}
```

The coding below is for another two festivals, but I thought we should use M(2010, date) instead? Since date includes year and day, but here we just need day.

```
M(2010, date);
O(2010, date);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So this some other author's code, not yours? And you want to understand the algorithms of date-time? The precise point of your question is not clear.

Comment: Correct, sorry not declaring clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

## Leap Year

That code is adjusting for [Leap Year](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year).

The Earth's orbit around the Sun (a year) and Earth's rotation on its axis (a day) are not synchronized. So we must adjustments to the date so as to keep our daily calendar correct. That adjustment is close to a quarter day but not quite. So every four years we add a day except every few centuries we don't except for every so often we do.

## Algorithm

From the Wikipedia article…

```
if (year is not divisible by 4) then (it is a common year)
else
if (year is not divisible by 100) then (it is a leap year)
else
if (year is not divisible by 400) then (it is a common year)
else (it is a leap year)
```

## Use Date-Time Library

Instead of rolling your own code, I strongly suggest you use a date-time library. For Java that means either [Joda-Tim](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)e or the java.time package in Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time, defined by JSR 310).

Avoid using the old java.util.Date and .Calendar classes bundled with Java as they are notoriously troublesome with flaws in both design and implementation.

Comment: Noteworthy, you list *three* adjusments where the OP's code only uses *two*. Fortunately, the last time that rule was needed was ancient history -- the year 2000.

Comment: Jongware, correct. Except a comment clarified that the code is not the poster's. She or he got the code from somewhere. The error you caught demonstrates why one should use a trusted date-time library rather than roll your own or grab some code! Date-time work is surprisingly complicated, confusing, and error-prone.